# Excel: Input Cell (i.e. runtime prompt) for PivotChart Instead of Slicer

Tags: excel, vba, filter, prompt, pivot-chart

Is there a way through VBA or some other excel functionality of which I'm unaware where you can update a filtered pivot chart based on keying in a value to a given cell (like a prompt) as opposed to a slicer? (Or is there some other dynamic chart option other than a pivot chart that will allow the charts to changed based on input values?)

The slicer is too visually busy for what I'm wanting to do. I've also looked into the "search box" trick, but I'd rather just update the chart based on an input value to a specific cell.

To try to add some code to help explain... If this were a (very simple) SQL query, it would look something like this with the ? prompt set to a specific cell but it would obviously return a chart (and with a time element not in the SQL) instead of a query:

```
  SELECT A.Unit, SUM(A.Amount)*-1
FROM Table A
WHERE (A.Unit = ?)
GROUP BY A.Unit
HAVING (Sum (A.Amount) <> 0)
ORDER BY 2
```

As always, I apologize if this type of question has already been answered and if I just haven't found it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I'm only looking to dynamically update a chart based on an input cell. I can and have used SUMPRODUCT to get the same information on another tab in a normal spreadsheet, non-chart format. I want to make a line-chart with the time element on the X-Axis, and the unit filter (as seen in the query above) be an individual input cell as opposed to a bulky slicer. I would share images if possible, but I can't without creating a link.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how complicated your data are, but could you just use SUMIFs formulas?

Cell H2 formula:

```
    =SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,$H$1,B:B,$G2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But can you dynamically update the chart with the formula? I already have SUMPRODUCTs that function the same as the SUMIFS with additional criteria. From everything I've seen online, the way to have a dynamically updated chart is through PivotCharts with slicers. 

I essentially just want to eliminate the slicer and have an input cell for the criteria. However, if it's possible to dynamically update the chart with sumifs/sumproduct, can you please share how to do that? 

Also, I'm going to edit my original post for more clarity. Actually need the time element on the X-axis.